# recursively search and copy specific files from all zip

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

I'm trying to move files from a number of zip archives using Windows batch scripting?

I have a list of files (test.txt, test2.txt, etc) stored on zip archives.

I'd like to search across all zip archives for each one of those files and then copy them to another directory.

Ideally files should not be removed from the original zip archives storing them.

My attempt was

```
@echo off
rem Prepare environment
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set content=test.txt;test2.txt;test3.txt

for %%u in (%content%) do call :doextractzip %%u
goto :eof

:doextractzip
for /R "c:\temp\ziptest" %%A in ("*.zip") do (
  call "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e %%A -oc:\temp\ziptest %%u -r
)
goto :eof
```

which is working fine **but** I'd like to call **content** from an external txt file

Also, I'd like to know if there area any better solution.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What console zip program are you using to open the zip files?

Comment: Only a bit of searching the internet would have shown you [Get Specific Files From Zip Files](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Get-Specific-9b35352f#content)

Comment: @Squashman I'm using 7zip but would accept a general approach.

Comment: @LotPings thank you. interesting but powershell script is not exactly the same. I'm interested in a strict windows scripting (dos) solution.